# Xcode iOS Simulator Questions

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have two questions about the iOS Simulator in Xcode for my Unity game:
I am using latest version of all the software involved.

- 1) Why is it so slow? (I have tried the Cmd+T solution and it does
  nothing. Note: The game runs smooth even on a real iPhone 4)
- 2) Why is the size of the iPad simulator screen bigger than my laptop screen? (I know you can
  scale it, but just curious why Apple always tries to make our life
  difficult)

Comment: Maybe cause your hardware Mac...

Answer (score 2):

1. When you run game on iOS simulator then your game image runs not completely running on your mobile hardware actually runs in **compression mode** so seems to be slow.
2. Having high resolutions Apple deceives have bigger number of pixels on their screen, so **its not Screen size but it Screen pixels** what we need to concern. And it is for creating more smooth effects on visuals for animation, it is to provide user **better quality graphics**, not to make your life difficult

Comment: But my Macbook Pro is also retina display with a 15' screen. So shouldn't all screen pixels in 12.9' iPad Retina display fit in a 15' Macbook Retina display? Or is there something I am missing?